# PCとモバイルで再生できて、ダウンロードの出来ない動画ストリーミングサーバが知りたい

Tags: android, ios, php, html5

現在動画のアプリケーションを検討しています。
要件としては下記です。

- Windows (PC版)、iOS、iPhone、Android スマホ、Androidタブレット、iPadで再生できる。
- 動画がダウンロードできないこととする。

そこで [Red5](https://code.google.com/p/red5/) のストリーミングサーバを使ってアプリケーションを開発したのですが
スマホ、タブレットが再生できません。(Flash が原因だと思います)

質問1 - [Red5](https://code.google.com/p/red5/) など RTMPを 再生するのに Flash を使わない方法があるものでしょうか？
質問2 - 上記がむりなら、ダウンロードできないようにする方法はあるのでしょうか？

Comment: 文中の *ダウンロード* は「ローカルファイルとしての保存」と訂正しても良いでしょうか? 文字通りに *ダウンロードできない* ようにしてしまうと、再生すらできなくなります。

Comment: タイトルを変更しましたが問題ないでしょうか？またRTMPはiOS標準では無理だったかと記憶していますが、単体アプリではなくSafariでの再生が前提でしょうか？

Comment: 誤字多くてすいません
ご指摘通りの修正で構いません。
再生は単体アプリではなくブラウザ（IE,Chrome,Firefox等）を想定しております。
Red5で実験したところ、MacのPC（iOS10）では問題なく再生できました。
プレイヤーは
下記のrtmp番を使用しました
https://flowplayer.org/
ただしスマホ、タブレットが対応できないのです

Answer (score 1):

Mobile Safariがサポートしている配信方式は

- プログレッシブダウンロード (HTTPでのファイルダウンロード)
- [Apple HTTP Live Streaming (HLS)](https://developer.apple.com/jp/documentation/StreamingMediaGuide.pdf)

のみですのでHLSが良いと思われます。これにはAndroidも対応しています。

配置としてはプレイリスト+10秒程度の小さな動画ファイル多数という構成になりますので、完全にダウンロード不可というわけではありませんが。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。
プレイリスト+tsに分割して登録しておけばプレイリストの順序で再生されると言った理解でよろしいでしょうか？
動作はMacのsafariだけということでしょうか？

Comment: HLSはM3U8プレイリストの記載順に動画を再生する方式です。ただ一般的なプレイリストというよりは動画をHLS形式に変換するというイメージですね。再生環境はAndroidであればブラウザが対応していて、PCの非対応ブラウザでもFlashプレイヤーが利用可能です。

Comment: ありがとうございます
非常に参考になりました。
試したところ、アンドロイドのChrome,IpadのChromeでも動きました。
（AndoroidのOperaは動かなかったですが）
MacPcはSafari以外とWindowsは全滅ですがFlashで再生させればほぼ解決です。
ありがとうございました